# How tear down integration tests

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, unit-testing

I want to do some integration tests on my project. Now I am looking for a mechanism that allow me execute some code before all tests begin and execute some code after all tests ends.

Note that I can have set up methods and tear down method for each tests but I need the same functionality for all tests as a whole.

Note that I using Visual Studio, C# and NUnit.

Comment: have you considered inheritance?

Comment: Daniel, I think that inheritance only solve my first problem, the second one (tearing down) is the most urgent.

Comment: What kind of logic is it? Individual test fixtures should be responsible for clearing their own test data/state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotate your test class with the NUnit.Framework.TestFixture attribute, and annotate you all tests setup and all tests teardown methods with NUnit.Framework.TestFixtureSetUp and NUnit.Framework.TestFixtureTearDown.

These attributes function like SetUp and TearDown but only run their methods once per fixture rather than before and after every test.

EDIT in response to comments:
In order to have a method run after ALL tests have finished, consider the following (not the cleanest but I'm not sure of a better way to do it):

```
internal static class ListOfIntegrationTests {
    // finds all integration tests
    public static readonly IList<Type> IntegrationTestTypes = typeof(MyBaseIntegrationTest).Assembly
        .GetTypes()
        .Where(t => !t.IsAbstract && t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(MyBaseIntegrationTest)))
        .ToList()
        .AsReadOnly();

    // keeps all tests that haven't run yet
    public static readonly IList<Type> TestsThatHaventRunYet = IntegrationTestTypes.ToList();
}

// all relevant tests extend this class
[TestFixture]
public abstract class MyBaseIntegrationTest {
    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void TestFixtureSetUp() { }

    [TestFixtureTearDown]
    public void TestFixtureTearDown() {
        ListOfIntegrationTests.TestsThatHaventRunYet.Remove(this.GetType());
        if (ListOfIntegrationTests.TestsThatHaventRunYet.Count == 0) {
            // do your cleanup logic here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this do not solve my problem, I do not want a tear down per fixture, I want a tear down for all fixtures as a whole.

Comment: TestFixtureTearDown seems to be do what you want http://nunit.org/index.php?p=fixtureTeardown&r=2.5

Comment: I agree that TestFixture attributes should be the way to go. In the very unlikely case that you really have to run code exactly once before/after all the tests: Have a look at NUnits TestRunner implementation and adapt it in a way, that it runs your code as desired. NUnit has quite a few extension points. You have to check yourself which one fits your needs best.