# Why not static destructors in C#

Tags: c#

I am interested in knowing why static destructors are not allowed in C#. Note that I am not supposing that they exist in any other language.

I could have a class like this one.

```
 class A
 {
      static A()
      {
         // here I can load a resource that will be avaliable for all instances 
         // of this class.
      }
 }
```

When the application ends I may need to release the resource.

So, the semantic of a static destructor could be the following: called when the application ends, for classes that contain it and were initialized in the app.

Comment: It is possible to achieve this behaviour with Singleton pattern and implementing the IDisposable interface.

Comment: if the application ends - wouldnt the resources its been using released anyway?

Comment: @YavgenyP 1) `AppDomain` unload and process termination are not the same 2) Not every resource gets released when the process terminates 3) Sometimes you need actual code in such a case, such as ensuring that data from a queue was written.

Comment: hold that resource as static property of the class.

Comment: Legoless, Singleton give us many other restrictions.

Comment: When application is closed, all memory that it was using will be free. So what's the sense of specific class destructor? Moreover what classes are you speaking about after application being closed?:)

Comment: @CodesInChaos, the asked question was about the end of an application, not an app domain. Theres also a difference between releasing a resource and having an application specific logic, such as en emptying a queue. But, yeah, it could make sense for an app domain level unload

Comment: @AlexeyBychkov The entire purpose of many destructors is to free resources not held in memory by the process.  Freeing file handles, closing network connections, dumping caches or flushing buffers, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your semantic is one possible one, but I guess you have not checked all effects it would have on the language. In most (more or less) dynamic languages I know, destruction is a much more complicated topic that it looks like. Why not call the destructor when the class is not referenced anymore? Or if the assembly is unloaded? In what order should destructor be called? ...?

If you just want to execute some code when the application ends, have a look at the .Net documentation. There are easier and more reliable ways to do so.

Comment: May be I don't just want to execute some code when the application ends, may be I want to make a class responsible of to release some static resource.

Comment: As I tried to explain in my answer: It seems that you have just one use case in mind, but ask for a general feature of a general purpose programming language. What does "release some static resources" mean? Just assume having two classes having such resources and they depend on each other. How should that be solved by the language? Just a hint: Why should I guess what you want to do? Just tell us your real purpose and we will try to help you with the solution. ;-)

Comment: Achim, I agree with you about the all semantics avaliables. This question come to my mind when I was trying to solve this problem:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12708943/how-tear-down-integration-tests

Answer (score 4):

> So, the semantic of a static destructor could be the following: - be
>   called when the application ends, on class that contains it and was
>   charged in the app.

Your semantic relies on your program doing an specific action at the end of execution and this is far more difficult to correctly handle than just a piece of code that runs at the end of normal execution of the process.

Think about transactions or file management operations. You have to manually handle crashes and unexpected termination of the process and try recovering at next run anyway, so then having an static destructor wouldn't help that much. .NET managed world favors upon [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) patterns instead of that. Now, if you're having serious problems with this, try to attach an event handler to the `DomainUnloaded` event on the `AppDomain` and perform your cleanup there.

You can, also, give a try to the *singleton* dispose way:

```
class A : IDisposable
{
    public static A Instance {get; private set;}

    public static A()
    {
        Instance=new A();
    }

    public void MethodA() {...}

    public void Dispose()
    {
        //...
    }

    ~A()
    {
        // Release your hard resources here
    }
}
```

And then, use the safe method:

```
A.Instance.MethodA();
```

Comment: I disagree, first of, the class that you show me isn't a Singleton one because have a default public constructor and the finalizer will be executed on each instance of this class. Yes we can fix this with a private constructor but this introduce other restrictions, for example with the inheritance.